# Access another relationship column in Laravel for difference

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm building a report with a comparison mode to compare two periods within my Laravel 10 application that's being used as an API. When in comparison mode I need to somehow dynamically figure out and append:

- The difference between the two values
- The difference as a percentage between the two values

I'm struggling to figure out how to do this at the database level via my query, I know I can do it via PHP foreach loops but I feel like there must be a more performant way at the DB level to do it, here's what my data structure looks like:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, I have three levels nested like:

- Company

  - Affiliate

    - Campaign

At each level there's commission stats and summary stats, then, when in comparison mode there's the historic.

i need to somehow, for example, dynamically add a `diff_total_sessions` to the historic relationship which is the difference between the current and previous, how can I achieve this?

Here's my function

```php
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 */
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'aggregation_mode' => 'required|string|in:auto,daily,hourly,minutely',
        'product' => 'required|exists:products,slug',
        'from' => 'required|date',
        'to' => 'required|date',
        'compare_from' => 'required_if:is_comparing,true|date',
        'compare_to' => 'required_if:is_comparing,true|date',
        'companies' => 'array|distinct',
        'affiliates' => 'array|distinct',
        'affiliate_campaigns' => 'array|distinct',
        'threshold_filters' => 'array|distinct',
        'is_comparing' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return new ApiValidationErrorResponse($validator->messages());
    }

    $currentUser = User::with('companies')->find(Auth::id());

    try {
        $report = Company::query();

        $report = $report->whereIn('id', $currentUser->companies->pluck('id')->toArray());

        $report = $report->select([
            'id',
            'company_name',
            'contact_first_name'
        ]);

        $report->with([
            'totalCompanyAffiliateSummaryStats' => function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->currentTimeframe();

                $query->select('company_id')
                        ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_sessions), 0) AS total_sessions')
                        ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_submits), 0) AS total_submits')
                        ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_leads), 0) AS total_leads')
                        ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_accepted), 0) AS total_accepted')
                        ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_declined), 0) AS total_declined')
                        ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_redirected), 0) AS total_redirected')
                        ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_accepted_redirected), 0) AS total_accepted_redirected')
                        ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(avg_processing_duration), 0) AS avg_processing_duration')
                        ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(avg_processing_accept_duration), 0) AS avg_processing_accept_duration')
                        ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(avg_processing_decline_duration), 0) AS avg_processing_decline_duration');

                if ($request->input('companies')) {
                    $query->whereIn('company_id', $request->input('companies'));
                }

                $query->groupBy('company_id');
            },
            'totalCommissionAffiliateSummaryStats' => function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->currentTimeframe();

                $query->select('company_id')
                        ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_revenue), 0) AS total_revenue')
                        ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_commission), 0) AS total_commission')
                        ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_profit_or_loss), 0) AS total_profit_or_loss');

                if ($request->input('companies')) {
                    $query->whereIn('company_id', $request->input('companies'));
                }

                $query->groupBy('company_id');
            },
        ]);

        if ($request->boolean('is_comparing')) {
            $report = $report->with([
                'historicTotalCompanyAffiliateSummaryStats' => function ($query) use ($request) {
                    $query->historicTimeframe();

                    $query->select('company_id')
                            ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_sessions), 0) AS total_sessions')
                            ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_submits), 0) AS total_submits')
                            ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_leads), 0) AS total_leads')
                            ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_accepted), 0) AS total_accepted')
                            ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_declined), 0) AS total_declined')
                            ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_redirected), 0) AS total_redirected')
                            ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_accepted_redirected), 0) AS total_accepted_redirected')
                            ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(avg_processing_duration), 0) AS avg_processing_duration')
                            ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(avg_processing_accept_duration), 0) AS avg_processing_accept_duration')
                            ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(avg_processing_decline_duration), 0) AS avg_processing_decline_duration');

                    if ($request->input('companies')) {
                        $query->whereIn('company_id', $request->input('companies'));
                    }

                    $query->groupBy('company_id');
                },
                'historicTotalCommissionAffiliateSummaryStats' => function ($query) use ($request) {
                    $query->historicTimeframe();

                    $query->select('company_id')
                            ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_revenue), 0) AS total_revenue')
                            ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_commission), 0) AS total_commission')
                            ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_profit_or_loss), 0) AS total_profit_or_loss');

                    if ($request->input('companies')) {
                        $query->whereIn('company_id', $request->input('companies'));
                    }

                    $query->groupBy('company_id');
                },
            ]);
        }

        $report = $report->with([
            'affiliates' => function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->select([
                    'id',
                    'company_id',
                    'user_id',
                    'aff_id',
                    'description',
                    'last_used_at'
                ]);

                if ($request->input('affiliates')) {
                    $query->whereIn('id', $request->input('affiliates'));
                }

                $query->with([
                    'totalAffiliateSummaryStats' => function ($query) use ($request) {
                        $query->currentTimeframe();

                        $query->select('affiliate_id')
                                ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_sessions), 0) AS total_sessions')
                                ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_submits), 0) AS total_submits')
                                ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_leads), 0) AS total_leads')
                                ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_accepted), 0) AS total_accepted')
                                ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_declined), 0) AS total_declined')
                                ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_redirected), 0) AS total_redirected')
                                ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_accepted_redirected), 0) AS total_accepted_redirected')
                                ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(avg_processing_duration), 0) AS avg_processing_duration')
                                ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(avg_processing_accept_duration), 0) AS avg_processing_accept_duration')
                                ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(avg_processing_decline_duration), 0) AS avg_processing_decline_duration');

                        $query->groupBy('affiliate_id');
                    },
                    'totalCommissionSummaryStats' => function ($query) use ($request) {
                        $query->currentTimeframe();

                        $query->select('affiliate_id')
                                ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_revenue), 0) AS total_revenue')
                                ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_commission), 0) AS total_commission')
                                ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_profit_or_loss), 0) AS total_profit_or_loss');

                        $query->groupBy('affiliate_id');
                    }
                ]);

                if ($request->boolean('is_comparing')) {
                    $query->with([
                        'historicTotalAffiliateSummaryStats' => function ($query) use ($request) {
                            $query->historicTimeframe();

                            $query->select('affiliate_id')
                                    ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_sessions), 0) AS total_sessions')
                                    ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_submits), 0) AS total_submits')
                                    ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_leads), 0) AS total_leads')
                                    ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_accepted), 0) AS total_accepted')
                                    ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_declined), 0) AS total_declined')
                                    ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_redirected), 0) AS total_redirected')
                                    ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_accepted_redirected), 0) AS total_accepted_redirected')
                                    ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(avg_processing_duration), 0) AS avg_processing_duration')
                                    ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(avg_processing_accept_duration), 0) AS avg_processing_accept_duration')
                                    ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(avg_processing_decline_duration), 0) AS avg_processing_decline_duration');

                            $query->groupBy('affiliate_id');
                        },
                        'historicTotalCommissionSummaryStats' => function ($query) use ($request) {
                            $query->historicTimeframe();

                            $query->select('affiliate_id')
                                    ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_revenue), 0) AS total_revenue')
                                    ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_commission), 0) AS total_commission')
                                    ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_profit_or_loss), 0) AS total_profit_or_loss');

                            $query->groupBy('affiliate_id');
                        }
                    ]);
                }

                $query->orderBy('last_used_at', 'desc');

                if (in_array('engagement_statistics', $request->input('threshold_filters', []))) {
                    $query->has('totalAffiliateSummaryStats');
                }

                if (in_array('financial_statistics', $request->input('threshold_filters', []))) {
                    $query->has('totalCommissionSummaryStats');
                }
            },
            'affiliates.campaigns' => function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->select([
                    'id',
                    'affiliate_id',
                    'user_id',
                    'campaign',
                    'last_used_at'
                ])->orderBy('last_used_at', 'desc');

                if ($request->input('affiliate_campaigns')) {
                    $query->whereIn('id', $request->input('affiliate_campaigns'));
                }

                $query->with([
                    'totalAffiliateCampaignSummaryStats' => function ($query) use ($request) {
                        $query->currentTimeframe();

                        $query->select('affiliate_campaign_id')
                                ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_sessions), 0) AS total_sessions')
                                ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_submits), 0) AS total_submits')
                                ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_leads), 0) AS total_leads')
                                ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_accepted), 0) AS total_accepted')
                                ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_declined), 0) AS total_declined')
                                ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_redirected), 0) AS total_redirected')
                                ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_accepted_redirected), 0) AS total_accepted_redirected')
                                ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(avg_processing_duration), 0) AS avg_processing_duration')
                                ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(avg_processing_accept_duration), 0) AS avg_processing_accept_duration')
                                ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(avg_processing_decline_duration), 0) AS avg_processing_decline_duration');

                        $query->groupBy('affiliate_campaign_id');
                    },
                    'totalCommissionSummaryStats' => function ($query) use ($request) {
                        $query->currentTimeframe();

                        $query->select('affiliate_campaign_id')
                                ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_revenue), 0) AS total_revenue')
                                ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_commission), 0) AS total_commission')
                                ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_profit_or_loss), 0) AS total_profit_or_loss');

                        $query->groupBy('affiliate_campaign_id');
                    }
                ]);

                if ($request->boolean('is_comparing')) {
                    $query->with([
                        'historicTotalAffiliateCampaignSummaryStats' => function ($query) use ($request) {
                            $query->historicTimeframe();

                            $query->select('affiliate_campaign_id')
                                    ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_sessions), 0) AS total_sessions')
                                    ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_submits), 0) AS total_submits')
                                    ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_leads), 0) AS total_leads')
                                    ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_accepted), 0) AS total_accepted')
                                    ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_declined), 0) AS total_declined')
                                    ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_redirected), 0) AS total_redirected')
                                    ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_accepted_redirected), 0) AS total_accepted_redirected')
                                    ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(avg_processing_duration), 0) AS avg_processing_duration')
                                    ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(avg_processing_accept_duration), 0) AS avg_processing_accept_duration')
                                    ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(avg_processing_decline_duration), 0) AS avg_processing_decline_duration');

                            $query->groupBy('affiliate_campaign_id');
                        },
                        'historicTotalCommissionSummaryStats' => function ($query) use ($request) {
                            $query->historicTimeframe();

                            $query->select('affiliate_campaign_id')
                                    ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_revenue), 0) AS total_revenue')
                                    ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_commission), 0) AS total_commission')
                                    ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(total_profit_or_loss), 0) AS total_profit_or_loss');

                            $query->groupBy('affiliate_campaign_id');
                        }
                    ]);
                }

                if (in_array('engagement_statistics', $request->input('threshold_filters', []))) {
                    $query->has('totalAffiliateCampaignSummaryStats');
                }

                if (in_array('financial_statistics', $request->input('threshold_filters', []))) {
                    $query->has('totalCommissionSummaryStats');
                }

            },
            'affiliates.products' => function ($query) {
                $query->withWhereHas('product', function ($query) {
                    $query->where('slug', 'payday')->select([
                        'id',
                        'user_id',
                        'company_id',
                        'slug',
                        'name'
                    ]);
                })->with([
                    'pingtreeGroup' => function ($query) {
                        $query->select([
                            'id',
                            'user_id',
                            'name',
                            'description'
                        ])->withCount([
                            'pingtreeGroupEntries'
                        ]);
                    },
                ])->withCount([
                    'splits'
                ]);
            }
        ])->whereHas('affiliates');

        if (in_array('engagement_statistics', $request->input('threshold_filters', []))) {
            $report = $report->has('totalCompanyAffiliateSummaryStats');
        }

        $report = $report->get();

        if (! $report || count($report) <= 0) {
            return new ApiSuccessResponse(null, [
                'message' => 'No pay out report found.',
            ], 404);
        }

        $report = $report->makeHidden([
            'abilities', 'roles', 'roles_to_remove'
        ]);

        // filter out users without affiliates here
        // TODO:we could improve this part soon.
        $report = $report->filter(function ($item, int $key) {
            return count($item->affiliates) > 0;
        })->values()->all();

        // $iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        //     new \RecursiveArrayIterator($report),
        //     \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
        // );



        // foreach (collect($report)->toArray() as $companyIndex => $company) {


        //     Log::debug('company', [
        //         'comp' => $company['total_company_affiliate_summary_stats']
        //     ]);

        //     foreach ($company['affiliates'] as $affiliateIndex => $affiliate) {
        //         foreach ($affiliate['campaigns'] as $campaignIndex => $campaign) {

        //         }
        //     }
        // }

        return new ApiSuccessResponse($report, [
            'is_comparing' => $request->boolean('is_comparing')
        ]);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return new ApiErrorResponse($e, [
            'message' => 'Unable to load report, please try again in a few minutes.',
        ]);
    }
}
```

I tried something like within one of the historic relationships:

```php
$query->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(totalCompanyAffiliateSummaryStats.total_sessions) - SUM(total_sessions), 0) AS diff_total_sessions');
```

But I've got so many columns to do this on that it would be a tonne of code duplication.

#### UPDATE

Just as a quick update to better illustrate what I'm trying to do, I've just written it as described via the PHP way of creating nested foreach loops etc, but this is really inefficient as it uses a lot of PHP memory and is slow at scale, how can I convert this into a database query that's part of my original query.

```php
foreach ($report as $companyIndex => $company) {

    // company level
    foreach ($company['total_company_affiliate_summary_stats'] as $col => $val) {
        if (str_contains($col, 'formatted')) continue;

        try {
            $report[$companyIndex]['historic_total_company_affiliate_summary_stats']["diff_$col"] = diff_change(
                $report[$companyIndex]['historic_total_company_affiliate_summary_stats'][$col],
                $report[$companyIndex]['total_company_affiliate_summary_stats'][$col]
            );
        } catch (\Exception $e) { }

        try {
            $report[$companyIndex]['historic_total_company_affiliate_summary_stats']["diff_change_$col"] = pct_change(
                $report[$companyIndex]['historic_total_company_affiliate_summary_stats'][$col],
                $report[$companyIndex]['total_company_affiliate_summary_stats'][$col]
            );
        } catch (\Exception $e) { }
    }

    foreach ($company['total_commission_affiliate_summary_stats'] as $col => $val) {
        if (str_contains($col, 'formatted')) continue;

        try {
            $report[$companyIndex]['historic_total_commission_affiliate_summary_stats']["diff_$col"] = diff_change(
                $report[$companyIndex]['historic_total_commission_affiliate_summary_stats'][$col],
                $report[$companyIndex]['total_commission_affiliate_summary_stats'][$col]
            );
        } catch (\Exception $e) { }

        try {
            $report[$companyIndex]['historic_total_commission_affiliate_summary_stats']["diff_change_$col"] = pct_change(
                $report[$companyIndex]['historic_total_commission_affiliate_summary_stats'][$col],
                $report[$companyIndex]['total_commission_affiliate_summary_stats'][$col]
            );
        } catch (\Exception $e) { }
    }

    foreach ($company['affiliates'] as $affiliateIndex => $affiliate) {

        // affiliate level
        foreach ($affiliate['total_affiliate_summary_stats'] as $col => $val) {
            if (str_contains($col, 'formatted')) continue;

            try {
                $report[$companyIndex]['affiliates'][$affiliateIndex]['historic_total_affiliate_summary_stats']["diff_$col"] = diff_change(
                    $report[$companyIndex]['affiliates'][$affiliateIndex]['historic_total_affiliate_summary_stats'][$col],
                    $report[$companyIndex]['affiliates'][$affiliateIndex]['total_affiliate_summary_stats'][$col]
                );
            } catch (\Exception $e) { }

            try {
                $report[$companyIndex]['affiliates'][$affiliateIndex]['historic_total_affiliate_summary_stats']["diff_change_$col"] = pct_change(
                    $report[$companyIndex]['affiliates'][$affiliateIndex]['historic_total_affiliate_summary_stats'][$col],
                    $report[$companyIndex]['affiliates'][$affiliateIndex]['total_affiliate_summary_stats'][$col]
                );
            } catch (\Exception $e) { }
        }

        foreach ($affiliate['total_commission_summary_stats'] as $col => $val) {
            if (str_contains($col, 'formatted')) continue;

            try {
                $report[$companyIndex]['affiliates'][$affiliateIndex]['historic_total_commission_summary_stats']["diff_$col"] = diff_change(
                    $report[$companyIndex]['affiliates'][$affiliateIndex]['historic_total_commission_summary_stats'][$col],
                    $report[$companyIndex]['affiliates'][$affiliateIndex]['total_commission_summary_stats'][$col]
                );
            } catch (\Exception $e) { }

            try {
                $report[$companyIndex]['affiliates'][$affiliateIndex]['historic_total_commission_summary_stats']["diff_change_$col"] = pct_change(
                    $report[$companyIndex]['affiliates'][$affiliateIndex]['historic_total_commission_summary_stats'][$col],
                    $report[$companyIndex]['affiliates'][$affiliateIndex]['total_commission_summary_stats'][$col]
                );
            } catch (\Exception $e) { }
        }

        foreach ($affiliate['campaigns'] as $campaignIndex => $campaign) {

            // affiliate campaign level
            foreach ($campaign['total_affiliate_campaign_summary_stats'] as $col => $val) {
                if (str_contains($col, 'formatted')) continue;

                try {
                    $report[$companyIndex]['affiliates'][$affiliateIndex]['campaigns'][$campaignIndex]['historic_total_affiliate_campaign_summary_stats']["diff_$col"] = diff_change(
                        $report[$companyIndex]['affiliates'][$affiliateIndex]['campaigns'][$campaignIndex]['historic_total_affiliate_campaign_summary_stats'][$col],
                        $report[$companyIndex]['affiliates'][$affiliateIndex]['campaigns'][$campaignIndex]['total_affiliate_campaign_summary_stats'][$col]
                    );
                } catch (\Exception $e) { }

                try {
                    $report[$companyIndex]['affiliates'][$affiliateIndex]['campaigns'][$campaignIndex]['historic_total_affiliate_campaign_summary_stats']["diff_change_$col"] = pct_change(
                        $report[$companyIndex]['affiliates'][$affiliateIndex]['campaigns'][$campaignIndex]['historic_total_affiliate_campaign_summary_stats'][$col],
                        $report[$companyIndex]['affiliates'][$affiliateIndex]['campaigns'][$campaignIndex]['total_affiliate_campaign_summary_stats'][$col]
                    );
                } catch (\Exception $e) { }
            }

            foreach ($campaign['total_commission_summary_stats'] as $col => $val) {
                if (str_contains($col, 'formatted')) continue;

                try {
                    $report[$companyIndex]['affiliates'][$affiliateIndex]['campaigns'][$campaignIndex]['historic_total_commission_summary_stats']["diff_$col"] = diff_change(
                        $report[$companyIndex]['affiliates'][$affiliateIndex]['campaigns'][$campaignIndex]['historic_total_commission_summary_stats'][$col],
                        $report[$companyIndex]['affiliates'][$affiliateIndex]['campaigns'][$campaignIndex]['total_commission_summary_stats'][$col]
                    );
                } catch (\Exception $e) { }

                try {
                    $report[$companyIndex]['affiliates'][$affiliateIndex]['campaigns'][$campaignIndex]['historic_total_commission_summary_stats']["diff_change_$col"] = pct_change(
                        $report[$companyIndex]['affiliates'][$affiliateIndex]['campaigns'][$campaignIndex]['historic_total_commission_summary_stats'][$col],
                        $report[$companyIndex]['affiliates'][$affiliateIndex]['campaigns'][$campaignIndex]['total_commission_summary_stats'][$col]
                    );
                } catch (\Exception $e) { }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can create two methods just like the 'historic_total_company_affiliate_summary_stats' method which returns the diff_change & pct_cnange respectively, inside the report model, IF you're using eloquent relations.

Comment: How? As you can see from my question I added that as PHP, but I'd like to do it at the database level. Please provide an example?

Comment: It would be easier if you share your Model file code, where you defined the relations.

Comment: Is there a particular one you'd like to see? There's over 12 each one hundreds of lines in length?

Comment: How do you fetch the columns like 'total_company_affiliate_summary_stats' and 'historic_total_company_affiliate_summary_stats'? Is there an Eloquent Relation defined in the model, OR are you using JOIN query?

Comment: Okay, I'll add the top-level `Company` model so you can see, it's a eloquent relation though. Both `Affiliate` and `AffilaiteCampaign` are identical. Please see the update.

Comment: Yeah as predicted, too much to put into Slack mate. `body` is too big.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254350/discussion-between-sabin-chacko-and-ryan-h).

Comment: You could have received better help if you shared the table schema(s), expected behavior, and sample data to allow others to reproduce your issue. Try [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: You've been around SO long enough to know what a [mre]. Insisting on doing this in-database seems like a pointless restriction. Just pull the 2 data sets, organize them into 2 matching `Collection` instances, and then work with that in an efficient manner.

Comment: could you create a view table to handle this?

Comment: This isn't helpful.